For any ring R, there exists a unique ring morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to R. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}$, is the only ring with this property.
I will admit, I am not really sure how to do this. My initial intuition was to assume that there exists another ring A with the same property as $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\exists f: \mathbb{Z}\to A$ and $g:A\to\mathbb{Z}$ where $f,g$ are the unique ring morphisms.
I would like to prove that $f$ and $g$ are injective. Since $Im(f)\subseteq A$ and $Im(g)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $f,g$ injective, then $\mathbf{card}(\mathbb{Z})\le \mathbf{card}(A)$ and $\mathbf{card}(A) \le \mathbf{card}(\mathbb{Z})$ therefore $\mathbf{card}(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbf{card}(A)$ so $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic hence $A = \mathbb{Z}$.
Firstly, I am not sure my reasoning above is right. Secondly, I am at a loss at how to prove injectivity of $f$ and $g$.  So far, I have tried this:
$\underline{\text{Injectivity of } f}$
Consider $\ker(f)$. The kernel of $f$ is an ideal and all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$. Let us assume $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}, n\neq 0$ such that $\ker(f) = n\mathbb{Z}$....... somehow this would lead to a contradiction I suppose..... Most likely related to the fact that $f$ is unique, but I can't figure out how.
I don't even know where to begin to prove the injectivity of $g$.
I would really appreciate any help/advice on how to complete this. Also, I am having a hard time trying to find these proofs online, so if anyone has any resources with these kinds of proofs, that would be great :) Thank you so much!!!

Are your rings assumed to have $1$ and morphism $\psi$ satisfies $\psi(1)=1$?

try to use that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are also the unique ring morphisms and so they must be the identities

Keep in mind the difference between being the $\textbf{only}$ ring such that blablabla and being the $\textbf{only}$ ring such that blablabla $\textbf{up to isomorphism}$ ! For example, the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times{0}$ also satisfies your property.

@user8268 I see, so $f\circ g$, being the composition of two ring morphisms, is a ring morphism itself. Since it maps $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself and is unique, it must be the identity (would I need to justify this further or can I just state this in the proof?). (apply the same logic for $g\circ f$). The compositions are the identities -> bijections, (+ each other's inverse). Since $f\circ g$ is a bijection, $g$ must be injective and $f$ must be surjective, and applying the same logic to $g\circ f$ yields that $f$ and $g$ are bijections, so $\mathbb{Z}$ and $A$ are isomorphic.

Category theory proves that initial (or final/terminal) objects in any category are unique up to isomorphism. This result in particular applies to initial objects in the category of rings. Any initial object must therefore be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, which is known to be initial.

Here is a more or less complete proof. Suppose $A$ that also satisfies the universal property of $\mathbb Z$, namely that for every ring $B$ there is a unique homomorphism $A\to B$. Then there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi$ from $A$ to $\mathbb Z$. Similarly, there is a unique homomorphism $\psi$ from $\mathbb Z$ to $A$. Then, $\psi\circ\varphi:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ is a ring homomorphism.

But we know there is only one ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$, so $\psi\circ\varphi$ is the identity homomorphism on $\mathbb Z$. Similarly, $\varphi\circ\psi$ is the identity homomorphism on $A$. Hence, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverses of each other, and so they are isomorphisms.
